# Typescript: Is there a simple way to convert an array of objects of one type to another

Tags: arrays, typescript, type-conversion, typescript2.0

So, I have two classes

```
Item { name: string; desc: string; meta: string}

ViewItem { name: string; desc: string; hidden: boolean; }
```

I have an array of Item that needs to be converted into an array of ViewItem.
Currently, I am looping through the array using for, instantiating ViewItem, assigning values to attributes and pushing it to the second array.

Is there a simple way to achieve this using lambda expressions? (similar to C#)
Or is there any other means?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You haven't showed enough of your code, so I'm not sure how you instantiate your classes, but in any case you can use the [array map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
class Item {
    name: string;
    desc: string;
    meta: string
}

class ViewItem {
    name: string;
    desc: string;
    hidden: boolean;

    constructor(item: Item) {
        this.name = item.name;
        this.desc = item.desc;
        this.hidden = false;
    }
}

let arr1: Item[];
let arr2 = arr1.map(item => new ViewItem(item));
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Item%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20desc%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20meta%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20ViewItem%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20desc%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20hidden%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(item%3A%20Item)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20item.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.desc%20%3D%20item.desc%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.hidden%20%3D%20false%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20arr1%3A%20Item%5B%5D%3B%0Alet%20arr2%20%3D%20arr1.map(item%20%3D%3E%20new%20ViewItem(item))%3B))

---

#### Edit

This can be shorter with `Object.assign`:

```
constructor(item: Item) {
    Object.assign(this, item);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

you can do use something like this.

```
const newdata = olddata.map((x) => {
        return { id: Number(x.id), label: x.label };
      });
```

as the converted column will be mapped to the newdata array.

Comment: How is `{ id: Number(...), label: ... }` related to the required `ViewItem` class from the question? The two existing answers from 2016 and 2017 also use Array.map but actually *answer the question* because they actually return `ViewItem` instances.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - maybe different POV, I liked this answer, I interpreted `newdata` being the array of `ViewItem`. maybe the answer could have used SO's exact parameters naming.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate method is to use `Object.keys`,

```
class Item {
    name: string;
    desc: string;
    meta: string
}

class ViewItem {
    name: string;
    desc: string;
    hidden: boolean;

    // additional properties
    additionalProp: boolean;

    constructor(item: Item) {
        Object.keys(item).forEach((prop) => { this[prop] = item[prop]; });

        // additional properties specific to this class
        this.additionalProp = false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let arr1: Item[] = [
    {
        name: "John Doe",
        desc: "blah",
        meta: "blah blah"
    }
];
let arr2: ViewItem[] = arr1.map(item => new ViewItem(item));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Item%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20desc%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20meta%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20ViewItem%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20desc%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20hidden%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20additional%20properties%0A%20%20%20%20additionalProp%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(item%3A%20Item)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.keys(item).forEach((prop)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20this%5Bprop%5D%20%3D%20item%5Bprop%5D%3B%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20additional%20properties%20specific%20to%20this%20class%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.additionalProp%20%3D%20false%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20arr1%3A%20Item%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22John%20Doe%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20desc%3A%20%22blah%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20meta%3A%20%22blah%20blah%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Jane%20Doe%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20desc%3A%20%22blah%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20meta%3A%20%22blah%20blah%20blah%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0Alet%20arr2%3A%20ViewItem%5B%5D%20%3D%20arr1.map(item%20%3D%3E%20new%20ViewItem(item))%3B%0Aconsole.log(arr2)%3B)