# convert an array of objects into a specific format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, dataformat

I have the below set of data that is in the format of objects within an array.

```
  const columns = [
    {
      "usage": 395226,
      "population": 1925117,
      "value": 21,
      "abv": "MN"
    },
    {
      "usage": 893129,
      "population": 4327541,
      "value": 21,
      "abv": "IL"
    }
  ]
```

I require the above set of data to be converted into below shown format. I have been stuck here for a while. I tried writing a function for converting this into the desired data format, but it didn't work.

```
let columns = [ 
                 ["abv", "population"], 
                 ["MN", 1925117], 
                 ["IL", 4327541] 
              ]
```

It would be a great help if anyone could help me solve this.
    Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: Is there a simple way to convert an array of objects of one type to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888305/typescript-is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-an-array-of-objects-of-one-type-to)

Comment: You should at least provide some code to show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz This is not a duplicate of that question, as this one is pure javascript and not TypeScript.

Comment: Please explain if there is any pattern in the new format that you require.

Comment: @TonyAbrams `Array.map()` is not a TypeScript-specific feature. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with a reducer:

```
 const cols = [
    {
      "usage": 395226,
      "population": 1925117,
      "value": 21,
      "abv": "MN"
    },
    {
      "usage": 893129,
      "population": 4327541,
      "value": 21,
      "abv": "IL"
    }
  ]

cols.reduce(function(acc, current) {
  acc.push([current.abv, current.population])
  return acc;
}, ["abv", "population"]);
```

Or if you don't like using `push`:

```
cols.reduce(function(acc, current) {

 acc = [
  ...acc,
  [current.abv, current.population]
 ]

 return acc;
}, ["abv", "population"]);
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/gudivuhuro/edit?html,js,console

Comment: You could easily use `["abv", "population"]` as an initial reducer value instead of an empty array

Comment: @IgorDymov Agreed. Editing the answer.

Comment: @Senelithperera I'm glad it helped, remember to 'accept' the answer that solved your question. 

Answer (score 0):

does this solve your problem ?

```
const columns = [
    {
      "usage": 395226,
      "population": 1925117,
      "value": 21,
      "abv": "MN"
    },
    {
      "usage": 893129,
      "population": 4327541,
      "value": 21,
      "abv": "IL"
    }
  ]
var k = [["abv", "population"]];
for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
    k.push([columns[i].abv, columns[i].population]);
}
console.log(k) // Expected expected output
```

and here is a generic Implementation if you so require that.

```
var names = ["abv", "population"];
var k = GetPropertiesInArray(columns, names); //[["abv", "population"]];

function GetPropertiesInArray(columns, names){
    var m = [];
    m.push(names);
    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
        var item = [];
        for(var j in names){
            item.push(columns[i][names[j]]);
        }
        m.push(item);
    }

    return m;
}

console.log(k);//Expected output
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your first data is static in desired output:

```js
const columns = [
    {
      "usage": 395226,
      "population": 1925117,
      "value": 21,
      "abv": "MN"
    },
    {
      "usage": 893129,
      "population": 4327541,
      "value": 21,
      "abv": "IL"
    }
  ];
  
  let cols = [];
  if (columns.length) {
      cols.push(["abv", "population"]);
      columns.forEach(item => {
          cols.push([item.abv, item.population])
      });
  }
  console.log(cols);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would end up using something like this:

```
const columns = [
    {
      "usage": 395226,
      "population": 1925117,
      "value": 21,
      "abv": "MN"
    },
    {
      "usage": 893129,
      "population": 4327541,
      "value": 21,
      "abv": "IL"
    }
];

let converted = columns.map((c) => [c.abv, c.population]);
converted.unshift(["abv", "population"]);
```